# Matching value to key

Tags: coldfusion

I have a very large struct and instead of key unfortunately I have only values available.
Is there a way to switch keys and values of struct or searching for a key by passing its value?

(I am using someone else's code and can't change it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use function [**StructFindValue**](http://cfdocs.org/StructFindValue) to find the struct key when you only know the value.

It returns an array of matches (but limited to one match by default), each array element containing a struct with three keys:

- Key   - the name of the key *(the thing you're after)*;
- Path  - the full path (for nested structs);
- Owner - the struct the value was obtained from.

#### Usage example:

Find keys pointing at the localhost IP address in the CGI scope (scopes are structs too):

```
<cfset Result = StructFindValue( CGI , '127.0.0.1' ) />

<cfdump var=#Result[1].Key# />
```

Outputs `remote_addr` - the first value found.

Note that the ordering of structs is not guaranteed - the first value may be different in different situations.

To get all results, simply specify the scope parameter as `all`:

```
<cfset Result = StructFindValue( CGI , '127.0.0.1' , 'all' ) />

<cfloop index=i from=1 to=#ArrayLen(Result)#>
    <cfdump var=#Result[i].Key# />
</cfloop>
```

Outputs `remote_addr` `remote_host` `local_addr`.